# How do I access a mounted ftp drive in windows via terminal (or git bash)?

Tags: windows, git, ftp

Pretty straight forward. I'm running windows through vmware to gain access to a read/write filesystem over FTP. I know on mac, I can mount in finder then access as a VOLUME (not as an ftp, since if I run in FTP, I lose git command ability) in terminal.

Since Windows mounts as r/w, how can I mount the FTP, then open it as a volume in terminal or git bash?

Comment: Reading your question made my brain hurt.  So you are trying to go Linux -> VMware -> Windows -> FTP?  AFAIK Windows doesn't mount FTP locations in the same manner as other resources (e.g. SMB shares) so I don't think it will work.

Comment: Belongs to http://superuser.com .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a virtual disk with a letter, that will pick the data from FTP, you need a third-party solution such as ExpanDrive or [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html).